# Applying `ar` (autoregressive model) for my data frame using `lapply` returns `numeric(0)`?

Tags: r, time-series, lapply

I'm working with a data.frame with all numeric data. I want to calculate the first order autoregressive coefficients for each column. I chose apply function to do the task and I defined a function as the following:

```
return.ar <- function(vec){
   return(as.numeric(ar(vec)$ar))
}
```

Then I applied it to a data frame I subset by column names as the following

```
lapply(df_return[,col.names],return.ar)
```

I was expecting to get a vector with ar coefficients. But instead I got a list with all the coefficients put in the first element like the following

```
$C.Growth
[1]  0.35629140 -0.07671252 -0.08699333 -0.27404355  0.21448342
[6] -0.19049197  0.06610908 -0.23077602

$Mkt.ret
numeric(0)

$SL
numeric(0)

$SM
numeric(0)

$SH
numeric(0)

$LL
numeric(0)

$LM
numeric(0)

$LH
numeric(0)
```

I don't understand what's going on.

The output of `dput(head(df_return))` looks like the following:

```
structure(list(Year = c(1929, 1930, 1931, 1932, 1933, 1934), 
C.Growth = c(0.94774902516838, 0.989078396169958, 0.911586749357132, 
0.996183522774413, 1.08170234030149, 1.05797659377887), S.Return = c(-19.7068321696574, 
-31.0834309393085, -45.2864376593084, -9.42504715968666, 
57.0992131145999, 4.05781718258972), Rf = c(4.79316783034255, 
2.58656906069154, 1.24356234069162, 0.954952840313344, 0.199213114599945, 
0.147817182589718), Inflation = c(-0.0531678303425544, -0.15656906069154, 
-0.15356234069162, -0.00495284031334435, 0.100786885400055, 
0.0321828174102824), Mkt.ret = c(-14.9668321696574, -28.6534309393085, 
-44.1964376593084, -8.47504715968666, 57.3992131145999, 4.23781718258972
), SL = c(-45.2568321696575, -35.1134309393085, -41.1864376593084, 
-5.28504715968666, 166.0392131146, 34.1378171825897), SM = c(-30.7368321696574, 
-31.9034309393085, -48.5364376593084, -8.94504715968666, 
118.7092131146, 19.7578171825897), SH = c(-36.7568321696575, 
-45.1834309393085, -51.5364376593084, 2.78495284031334, 125.7792131146, 
7.95781718258972), LL = c(-19.6968321696574, -26.2734309393085, 
-36.2264376593084, -7.31504715968666, 44.1492131145999, 10.6978171825897
), LM = c(0.673167830342554, -29.2434309393085, -59.9864376593084, 
-16.7150471596867, 89.4692131145999, -2.93218281741028), 
LH = c(-4.35683216965745, -43.1934309393085, -57.7364376593084, 
-4.30504715968666, 114.7092131146, -21.8421828174103)), .Names =   c("Year", 
"C.Growth", "S.Return", "Rf", "Inflation", "Mkt.ret", "SL", "SM", 
"SH", "LL", "LM", "LH"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Zheyuan Li I tried that too but the same result returned.

Comment: I tried 'lapply(df_return[col.names],return.ar)' but still got the same result..

Comment: col.names is defined as `c(c("C.Growth","Mkt.ret"),names(df_return)[7:12])`. Sure I'm not merely trying to tell you it's not working, I appreciate your help.

Comment: I guess that's also plausible. Yet the problem here is that all the ar coefficients are put into the $C.Growth part. I've tried a explicit for loop for all the columns. I get the same coefficients. I just wonder why the result I get from using apply end up with having all those nested in the $C.Growth part.

Comment: There are 8 columns of interest, each column has one ar coefficient. You can see there are 8 numeric values in the $C.Growth part.

Comment: I run the following for loop instead `ar.vec <- numeric()
for (name in col.names){
  ar.vec <- c(ar.vec, return.ar(df_return[name]))
}` and get now ar.vec is `[1]  0.35629140 -0.07671252 -0.08699333 -0.27404355  0.21448342
[6] -0.19049197  0.06610908 -0.23077602` notice these are same numbers I got from using apply or lapply. I just one they all got nested in the `$C.Growth` part. Can you help me?

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Thanks for your time. I ran another round of test and you're right. Your help is much appreciated. Every now and then, you'll probably run into a rookie like me who's struggling with things that seem rudimentary to you. That's common and fine. I'm not an expert at this, I have my thing in other fields. I'll never found such bug by myself, so you pretty much saved me, I hope you know that and I certainly hope you feel happy about it. Let's all be a little bit more tolerant with stupid questions.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi I'm glad I didn't ruin your day. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you include your data, diagnose becomes easy.

`ar` will do auto-section of `p` based on AIC. Some of your columns have strong evidence to be white noise, hence `ar` has selected `p = 0`, in which case `$ar` field will be `numeric(0)`.

I suggest you also use the following:

```
lapply(df_return[col.names], function (x) ar(x, order.max = 5)$order)
```

or even better:

```
fit_ar <- function(x) ar(x, order.max = 5)[c("order", "ar")]
lapply(df_return[col.names], fit_ar)
```

The latter returns both `p` as well as AR coefficients for each column. I have set `order.max = 5`, so that `ar` won't choose it itself.

---

You tried to convince me that `lapply` is doing wrong, by using this `for` loop:

```
ar.vec <- numeric()
for (name in col.names)
   ar.vec <- c(ar.vec, return.ar(df_return[[ name ]]))
```

But unfortunately you **won't get anything useful** from this. Note you used concatenation `c()`, thus there is no way to tell which coefficient is for which column.

`lapply` is not identical to such loop. You should use:

```
ar.vec <- vector("list", length(col.names))
for (i in 1:length(col.names))
   ar.vec[[i]] <- return.ar(df_return[[ col.names[i] ]])
```